# converting a list with 0's and 1's to a bitarray (with bitarray module) and outputting to a binary file error

Tags: python, file, binary, output

I have a unique problem (at least as far as I can tell from the hours I've spent here on SO and out on google searches).

I have a list of 0 and 1 integers of varying list length, for example:

```
[0, 1, 0, 0 ,1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...]
```

I'm converting this list into a `bitarray`, like so:

```
from bitarray import bitarray
def binWise(sequence):
   newseq = bitarray(sequence)
   return newseq
```

and this returns a binary output in the format:

```
b'01001000001'
```

however, when I try to write this to a file directly as binary, I get

```
TypeError: 'bitarray' does not support the buffer interface
```

Is there any way to output the binary data directly to a binary file?
I don't mind 3rd party module suggestions at all. But the simpler the better.

Comment: Are you opening the file in binary mode?

Comment: @JonClements: that's what the exception suggests, actually.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the length of the bitarray is not a multiple of 8?

Comment: So what did you expect to write to the file? `'0'` and `'1'` *characters*, or a byte per 8 bits? `01001000` is 0x48 in hexadecimal, or `'H'` in ASCII, for example, so you could write `'H'` to the file in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use one of the following methods to produce a `bytes` or `str` string object:

- `.to01()` produces a string of `'0'` and `'1'` characters.
- `.tobytes()` produces a `bytes` object with each sequence of 8 bits (a byte) converted to a byte in the `bytes` sequence. The `bitarray` is padded to a length that is a multiple of 8.
- `.tofile(f)` writes the `bitarray` information to a file (in binary mode), again padded to a length that is a multiple of 8.

Answer (score 1):

To pack zeros and ones into a binary bit-wise format, numpy's `packbits` can be used:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.packbits([1, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 0, 0, 1])
>>> x
array([129], dtype=uint8)
```

`uint8` means that numpy is displaying each byte in the data as unsigned-integers.

This array can be written to file:

```
>>> with open('output.dat', 'wb') as f:
...    f.write(x)
...
```

Packbits will pack your data into as many bytes as it needs.  Data that is not even multiplex of 8 long, is handled easily:

```
>>> x = np.packbits([1, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
>>> x
array([129, 192], dtype=uint8)
```

As you can see, ninth and tenth bits, `1, 1`, are put in the second byte starting with the 'high' bits.

Comment: This worked great! Thank you so much, I Had no idea NumPy had that functionality.